# Not able to select operating system

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I had a little issue with my laptop and had to send it to the company for repair.I had dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu and Windows .As far as I know my data was not tampered in any way. But after I got my laptop I'm not getting an option to select the operating system as before. When I checked, that partition is still there. How can I log into Ubuntu again.

TIA

Edit: The laptop is XPS 9370 and the two OS were Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I was informed that there was some problem in a connection in motherboard so they just replaced the connection.

Comment: What is AFAIK ?

Comment: Please provide more details about the laptop and about the operations performed by the company if you know what they did.

Comment: Please check the edits

Answer (score 0):

Normally for many laptop manufacturers they put windows as the default OS, so once you upgrade your motherboard or BIOS system, it will redirect to the windows boot as default boot. In this case, you'd better enter the bios at start up, and put ubuntu UEFI first, or if the ubuntu boot doesn't appear in the menu, maybe you should change the boot option as "legacy first". Remember to save your setting and you can reboot and re-enter the bios to make sure that ubuntu is now the default boot OS, because I've seen computers that are stubborn and requires you to configure more than one time. Until you next time when you see that ubuntu is the default OS, I think then everything is OK .

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I checked the boot sequence and grub was removed from it. So I added it by adding a boot option and selecting EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi as a boot option and now it works fine. Thank you everyone for the support and the answers.